# Shortcut to leave textfield that accepts tab in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How to leave a textfield that accepts tab as valid input in eclipse by using only the keyboard? See image for an exaple.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `ctrl-tab` has the same behaviour as `tab`, but it will also work when tab is accepted as valid input.